# How can I check for the file that is present in the other directory and not in the workspace from a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, charts, jenkins-pipeline, devops, pipeline

I have a tar/zip file in a git repo. This tar/zip file needs to be put up in the directory named as 'chart_directory'. Using my Jenkinsfile, I want to implement the logic that it would download this tar/zip file from the git repo only if 'chart_directory' does not already contain a copy of the tar/zip file present in the git repo.
eg - There is a file named 'Charts.tgz' in a git repo named 'testing.git'
I need to download this 'Charts.tgz' file in 'chart_directory' only if 'chart_directory' does not already contain the file 'Charts.tgz'. If Charts.tgz is already present in 'chart_directory', then it should skip to download the file.

Comment: What do you mean by "fetch one particular file"? Do you mean copy a file from somewhere else on the filesystem to the workspace? Do you mean download a file from somewhere?

Comment: I mean downloading a file from a different directory

Comment: If your Jenkins server is running a Unix OS, use the [`cp` command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html). If your Jenkins server is running a Windows OS, use the [`copy` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy).

Comment: I have a tar/zip file in a git repo. This tar/zip file needs to be put up in the directory named as 'chart_directory'. Using my Jenkinsfile, I want to implement the logic that it would download the tar/zip file from the git repo only if 'chart_directory' does not already contain a copy of the tar/zip file present in the git repo.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I am assuming your Jenkins server is running a Unix OS, since you don't specify the OS in your question.

You can check if the `Charts.tgz` file exists locally in `chart_directory` with the [`find` command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

```sh
find chart_directory -type f -name Charts.tgz
```

`-type f` tells `find` to search for regular files, and `-name Charts.tgz` tells `find` to search specifically for `Charts.tgz`.

`find` will have an exit code of zero if it finds nothing. To work around this, you can pipe to `read` to get a non-zero exit code if `find` finds nothing. (`read` has a non-zero exit code if it encounters an [`EOF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file), which is exactly what will happen if `find` doesn't find anything.)

In your code, you can download `Charts.tgz` only if it is not present in `chart_directory` like this:

```sh
find chart_directory -type f -name Charts.tgz | read || {
    # Your code here (between the '{' and '}') to clone the git repo
    # to retrieve Charts.tgz
}
```

What the `||` operator does is the expression on the left side is only evaluated if the expression on the right side has a non-zero exit code. In this case, this means the code between the `{` and `}` will only be evaluated if `find` doesn't find anything.